# Shiny Column rendering error

Tags: r, shiny, dt

This is a Q on the Column rendering example (4.4)provided in this link. 
http://rstudio.github.io/DT/options.html

I have implemented the example code described above to abbreviate character strings that are wider than 100 characters using the first 100 characters plus an ellipsis (…), and the full character string is displayed as a tooltip when you mouse over the cell. This works well as long as the column with custom rendering has full text in it. However, when it encounters an empty cell the table is not displayed and it shows " Processing..." on shiny browser. On disabling this custom rendering I am able to display the table with empty fields as expected. 
Did anyone had similar issue, any suggestion to overcome this ?

Below is my custom column rendering code.

```
output$PM_output <- DT::renderDataTable(
    expr =  DT::datatable(PubmedOutput(PubmedSearch()),
                          class   = 'cell-border stripe compact hover',
                          escape  = F, selection = 'multiple',
                          options = list(
                            initComplete = JS("function(settings, json) {",
                                "$(this.api().table().header()).css({
                                'background-color': '#303030',
                                'color': '#FFFF00'});","}"),
                            autoWidth  = T,
                            LengthMenu = c(5, 30, 50),
                             columnDefs = list(list(
                               targets  = 6,
                               render   = JS(
                                 "function(data, type, row, meta) {",
                                 "return type === 'display' && data.length > 100 ?",
                                 "'<span title=\"' + data + '\">' +
                                 data.substr(0, 100) + '...</span>' : data;", "}"))),
                            columnDefs = list(list(
                              targets  = c(1:8),
                              className = 'dt-center')),
                            pageLength = 1, server = T)))
```

The code that generate the Column 6 that I have passed custom rendering on.

```
PM.ID <- c("26391251","26372702","26372699","26371045") # does not output table
fetch.pubmed <- entrez_fetch(db = "pubmed", id = PM.ID,
                             rettype = "xml", parsed = T)
abstracts = xpathApply(fetch.pubmed, '//PubmedArticle//Article', function(x) xmlValue(xmlChildren(x)$Abstract))
abstracts #  ID 26372702, 26372699 has no abstract. and returns NA
```

Any inputs and suggestion. 
P.S: Is there a better way to display data other than ellipsis/ tooltip ?
the code is too big to paste it all, hence picking only the parts where I noticed the issue. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition `data.length > 100` is not enough: you need to make sure `data` is a character string first. In your case, `data` may be `null` (converted from R's `NA` to JavaScript), and `null.length` will trigger an error. Replace

```
type === 'display' && data.length > 100
```

with a more rigorous condition:

```
type === 'display' && typeof data === 'string' && data.length > 100
```

Comment: Is this the right way to pass arguments? I don't get any display of the text   `columnDefs = list(list(`
                              `targets  = 6,`
                              `render   = JS(`
                                `"function(data, type, row, meta) {",`
                                `"return type === 'display'",` 
                                `"typeof data === 'string' && data.length > 100 ?",`
                                `"'<span title=\"' + data + '\">' +`
                                `data.substr(0, 100) + '...</span>' : data;", "}"))),`

Comment: `"return type === 'display' && data.length > 100 ? ",`
 `"typeof data === 'string' ",` This Does not display any text. The code in above comment display "True" for Column 6. Please let me know if the way I am passing arguments in wrong. Thank you

Comment: Hii yuhi, Thank you very much. Implementing your edited code gave a popup warning `unknown parameter 6 for row 0 check notes in` datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4. When I clicked OK, it did not display text in Column 6. So, I followed the troubleshooting steps described in text notes. I tried to implement `defaultContent:" "` as null for column 6 which did not display any table. Please find the new edited code in the Q.

Comment: I believe `defaultContent` is completely irrelevant. Please paste what you tried exactly before you started to try  `defaultContent`.

Comment: Please find the Edit-2 with complete code. This gives the warning I mentioned in previous comment. When I click OK on the popup, it displays table, but nothing in the column 6.

Comment: You didn't follow what I wrote above: you removed `return` inside the JS function. Please just insert `typeof data === 'string' &&` into the condition, and don't touch anything else.

Comment: Ah...!! It is solved now. and it is working. Thank you

Comment: Can you direct me to the material where I can learn about how to pass JS arguments in Rshiny ? For instance, I did not find argument `typeof data === 'string' ` in Rstudio github website ? I have no clue that I can pass arguments like these.

Comment: You will have to learn JavaScript, which is a different language. I do not have a book or website to recommend to you, but I'm sure there are millions of tutorials online :)